# Sort ListBox accoring to filename if Items are filepaths

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, listbox

I have a `ListBox` that contains `ListBoxItem`s, who's `Content` are strings that are either full filepaths or cropped paths, if the actual path is too long (the start of the filepath is cropped, e.g. "C:\MyFolder1\MyFolder2\MyFile.df" -> "...1\MyFolder2\MyFile.df"). The `Tag`s of the items are custom objects that contain the full filepath, the filename and if necessary the cropped filepath:

```
internal class MyClass
{
    internal string filePath, filePathCropped, fileName;
    internal ListBoxItem listBoxItem;

    //the paths are set somewhere here, whenever a file is opened and then an event is
    //raised that adds them to the ListBox. filePathCropped is equal to filePath, if
    //the path is short enough.
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    internal void AddFileToList(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyClass myClass = sender as MyClass ;
        myClass.listBoxItem = new ListBoxItem
        {
            Content = myClass.filePathCropped,
            Tag = myClass
        };
        listBoxOpenFiles.Items.Add(myClass.listBoxItem);
        SortFileList();
    }

    private void SortFileList()
    {
        //I would like to sort my list here according to fileName
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I am not really sure how the sorting mechanism exactly works. There are several topics on this on SO, but they mostly concern sorting according to the actual strings in the list but that is not exactly what I am trying to achieve here.

I tried this:

```
private void SortFileList()
{
    listBoxOpenFiles.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(
        new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription((Tag as MyClass).fileName, 
        System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
}
```

But that raises a `NullRefenceException` since `Tag` is not set. I am not completely sure, how to either access the `TagProperty` of my items or how to sort not according to the whole content string, but only the last bit (which is of course also equal to the file name).

Comment: Did you make sure that the Tag of **every** item in your listbos is set to something (i.e. an Instance of MyClass)?

Comment: Yes, as I only add it via the method described above, which always sets the Tag to the object containing the item.

Comment: Then Tag should never be null!

Comment: I think the issue here is that simply trying to access it via "Tag as MyClass" does not connect the "Tag" to the current Item that is being sorted, but rather to the general class definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more research in a different direction, I have found a fairly straightforward solution [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-sort), which I haven't thought about before that doesn't use collections but rather an "old fashioned" way.

```
private void SortFileList()
{
    int length = listBoxOpenFiles.Items.Count;
    string[] keys = new string[length];
    ListBoxItem[] items = new ListBoxItem[length];

    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        keys[i] = ((listBoxOpenFiles.Items[i] as ListBoxItem).Tag as MyClass).FileName;
        items[i] = listBoxOpenFiles.Items[i] as ListBoxItem;
    }

    Array.Sort(keys, items);
    listBoxOpenFiles.Items.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        listBoxOpenFiles.Items.Add(items[i]);
    }
}
```

This might not be the most elegant solution considering that it's a WPF program, but it works without having to change anything in the previous code.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you're actually using **properties**, instead of variables:

```
internal class MyClass
{
    internal string filePath, filePathCropped;
    internal ListBoxItem listBoxItem;

    internal string FileName {get;set;}
}
```

Secondly, you should specify the property which the sort is applied:

```
listBoxOpenFiles.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(
        new SortDescription("Tag.FileName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

That said, your code is getting already quite confusing: you should really handle this with XAML only. Also, you do not need to call `Sort` method. Make sure your underlying collection is using `ObservableCollection`, and it will be taken care of.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will check it in a second. Funny fact, I am actually using properties, but thought that wouldn't make a difference, so I "simplified" it =D

Comment: Okay, I have tried your suggestion and it doesn't work like that, it seems to not sort anything whatsoever /=
And about the confusing code, you are of course right, the issue here is that items are added dynamically and I don't have any control to change it, unfortunately.